# R: converting daily data to weekly data

Tags: r

When using to.weekly to convert the following daily data to weekly frequency, I encounter an an error in columns 5 & 6: 
Original daily data: column 5: Adjusted price & column 6: Volume
converted to Weekly data: Column 5: Volume (weekly) and column 6: Adjusted price (in name), but contains Volume data

```
data.AMZN<-read.table(text=
          "AMZN.Open AMZN.High AMZN.Low AMZN.Close AMZN.Adjusted AMZN.Volume
2011-01-03    181.37    186.00   181.21     184.22        184.22     5331400
2011-01-04    186.15    187.70   183.78     185.01        185.01     5031800
2011-01-05    184.10    187.45   184.07     187.42        187.42     3418800
2011-01-06    186.50    187.41   185.25     185.86        185.86     3179700
2011-01-07    187.88    188.45   183.74     185.49        185.49     5221700")

data.weekly<-read.table(text=
           "wk.Open wk.High wk.Low wk.Close wk.Volume wk.Adjusted
2010-12-31  181.96  182.30 179.51   180.00   3451900     3451900
2011-01-07  181.37  188.45 181.21   185.49  22183400     5221700
2011-01-14  185.04  188.94 182.51   188.75  15899000     3662800
2013-12-31  399.41  399.92 392.45   398.79   4483600     1996500")
```

Comment: What is `to.weekly`? Your method or another package's method? And what is the error?

Comment: it is a method in xts; Error: Instead of Adjusted Closing price, I am getting volume twice

Comment: Please show full code block using your posted data including all `library` lines. This sets up a [MCVE]. You can edit your own post (see link below question).

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear what you did between `data.AMZN` and `data.weekly`. Please note that in your data the dates are not a variable, they are rownames.  Therefore first thing to do is to move names to column.

I would suggest to do the following with your data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
data.weekly2 = data.AMZN %>%
  rownames_to_column(., "date")%>% # as the name suggests
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% # convert characters to date
  mutate( week_start = floor_date(date, "week")) %>% # creates column with week start date
  group_by(week_start) %>% # now yo can do with data what you need i.e.:
  summarise(AMZN.Volume = sum(AMZN.Volume))
```

All the best,
M